# Does a datasheet paramaters of an IGBT gives you a DC , AC rms or an average value

Tags: power-electronics, datasheet, igbt

For an example if you look at this datasheet for an IGBT [datasheet](https://www.semikron.com/dl/service-support/downloads/download/semikron-datasheet-skm100gb176d-22890855) ,

It has values for

1) Vces

2) Ic

3) VGes

ect.

Does these values give you a **DC**, or **AC RMS** or an **average value**?

Comment: They're usually a DC value unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 0):

Peak applies to all absolute maximum **Parameters**, unless there is a duty cycle then refer to graphs for time duration.